# How is it defined for the limsup of a sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I know the definition of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$, but what is the definition for
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{sup}_{x\in[0, 1]} f_n(x)$$

Does it mean, first fix $n$ for example, $n=5$, then compute the $\sup$ of $f_5(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ ? If $f_n(x)$ is continuous for each $n$ then  the $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f_5(x)=\max_{x\in[0,1]}f_5(x)$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{sup}_{x\in[0, 1]} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\max_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x)\right)$$

Is this interpterion correct?

**Edit:** thank you to @peter , and can I interpret it as following? (Assume continuity)

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{sup}_{x\in[0, 1]} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup \left(\max_{x\in[0,1]}f_n(x), \max_{x\in[0,1]}f_{n+1}(x),...,\right)$$

Comment: Yes seems correct to me!

Comment: I have certainly never seen that notation - as a thing. For one, the limit wouldn't always be defined. Are you sure you don't mean the function $ \lim \sup_{n\to \infty} f_n$ (without the $x\in [0,1]$ subscript)? This is defined pointwise: $$ ( \lim \sup_{n\to \infty} f_n)\, (x)=  \mathop{\lim \sup}_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = \inf_{k\to\infty} \Big( \sup_{n\ge k}f_n(x)\Big).$$
Namely, for each (fixed) $x$, calculate the lim sup of the sequence $a_n= f_n(x).$

Comment: That's what I am confused, it has two "variables" n and x, I am not sure which is fixed first @peterag

Comment: If $f_n(x)=1$ identically for $n$ odd, and $f_n(x)=0$ identically for $n$ even, then, using your recipe, that is, by fixing $n$ first and taking the sup over the $x$, you would be left with calculating the limit of the sequence $1,0,1,0,\cdots$, which does not exist. On the other hand by fixing $x$ first, the lim sup exists or each $x$, and equals $1$ (for all $x$!). Calculating pointwise (i.e., fixing $x$ first)  is what is usually meant by the function $\lim\sup f_n$, which always exists.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) But I have never seen your notation (with $x\in[0,1]$ as a subscript), so ....  Take my 'usually' comment with a grain salt, and check (with) your source?

Comment: Thank you ,and I edit it, I can interpret it in this way? @peterag

Comment: I am afraid I am going to bail out at this point - I've never seen that notation.

Comment: I would interpret it as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]} f_n(x)\right)$$ The lim and sup are two distinct operations applied in succession, not a single operation involving two variables.